# Catia VBA, How to get "Bill of material" to an array

Tags: vba, catia

I want to get 2 parameters in "bill of material".
first "Length" in structure workbench, second is "quantity".
I try to find these 2 parameters in

```
CATIA.Documents.Item(Document).Product.ReferenceProduct
```

But can't.
I have an idea. I try find a way to get "Bill of material" into an array.
I found a code write Bill of material to excel file.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim productDocument1 As productDocument
Set productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim product1 As Product
Set product1 = productDocument1.Product

Dim assemblyConvertor1 As AssemblyConvertor
Set assemblyConvertor1 = product1.GetItem("BillOfMaterial")

assemblyConvertor1.[Print] "XLS", "D:\BOM.xls", product1
```

How to get "Bill of material" data into an array? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "lenght"? Is this a parameter? Where is it located in the tree? And "quantity", is it also a parameter or how often the parameter/product is in our Productdocument?

Comment: Hi Shrotter, thank for reply!
This is "Length", the product created in "Structure Design" workbench, Then you can found length of part in "Bill of material"
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gKkAD3Wz5oNW6UF_hZ9TsTg5BhptPfdO/view?usp=sharing]
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y8M0NTxKt6yuNR1bknf0RlOqNsZacamI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So you could use _AssemblyConverter_ (include _Lenght_ parameter (macro recorder)) to create a txt. Then parse this file. Or write your own BOM function

Comment: There is no way of direct assignment.
Writing, reading, and parsing files increases processing time.
The "quantity" I can find by counting the frequencies on the "Tree".
But I can't find "Length" anywhere. If there is any way i can get it please let me know.

Comment: Please check the _UserRefProperties_? I guess this parameter is located there. So you could loop trough the products-collection, get the ReferenceProduct and access the UserRefproperties

Comment: I know what you mean. But "Length" not exists in "user parameters".
This "Length" exists in only [STRMember](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VoVFdXL_yf6hnNmpHanyf4aqMyNPMg2U/view?usp=sharing)
[Parameter](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oX9C17tfy8T8Qaq-Zyfva0JOHYj5RVT1/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length parameter of elements of the structure design apparently only available trough the *StrComputeServices*
Example:

```vb
Sub CATMain()

Dim oRootProduct as Product
Dim oInstanceProduct as Product
Dim oStrWB as Workbench
Dim oStrServices As StrComputeServices

Set oRootProduct = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Product
Set oInstanceProduct = oRootProduct.Products.Item(1)
Set oStrWB = CATIA.ActiveDocument.GetWorkbench("StrWorkbench")
Set oStrServices = oStrWB.StrComputeServices

MsgBox CStr(oStrServices.GetLength(oInstanceProduct))

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah! it worked.
Shrotter, Thank you so much!
wish you a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed this code below if it can help you :
https://www.catiavb.net/sourceCodeCATIA.php#getbom
You can find the function to get `'MaLangue'` in same website (to return language used by CATIA if necessary). Or you can delete every line who refers to `'MaLangue'`. To launch the sub you can write `GetBOM(Catia.ActiveDocument.Product)` if you want to get the BOM of the root product. Or you can launch for for an other product from the root.

You can then read lines  of the txt file (thanks to a stream reader) and split by every `vbTab` to get your array. The advantage is that you will have a bill of materials that either lists all the parts, or only lists the first level as required by certain customer standards

```
'Genere la BOM
    Public Sub  GetBOM(p As  Product)
 
        Dim  NomFichier As String  = My. Computer . FileSystem . SpecialDirectories . Temp & "\BOM.txt"
        Dim  AssConvertor As AssemblyConvertor
        AssConvertor =  p. GetItem ( "BillOfMaterial" )
        Dim nullstr ( 2 )
        If  MaLangue =  "Anglais" Then   
            nullstr( 0 ) = "Part Number" 
            nullstr( 1 ) = "Quantity"   
            nullstr( 2 ) = "Type"        
        ElseIf  MaLangue =  "Francais" Then 
            nullstr( 0 ) = "Référence" 
            nullstr( 1 ) = "Quantité" 
            nullstr( 2 ) = "Type" 
        End If 
 
        AssConvertor. SetCurrentFormat (nullstr)
 
        Dim  VarMaListNom( 1 )
        If  MaLangue =  "Anglais" Then 
            VarMaListNom( 0 ) = "Part Number"
            VarMaListNom( 1 ) = "Quantity"
        ElseIf  MaLangue =  "Français" Then
            VarMaListNom( 0 ) = "Référence"
            VarMaListNom( 1 ) = "Quantité"
        End If
 
        AssConvertor. SetSecondaryFormat (VarMaListNom)
        AssConvertor. Print ( "HTML", NomFichier, p )
 
        ModifFichierNomenclature (My. Computer . FileSystem . SpecialDirectories . Temp & "\BOM.txt" )
 
 
    End Sub
    Sub ModifFichierNomenclature(txt As String )
 
        Dim  strtocheck As String  = ""
        If  MaLangue =  "Francais" Then
            strtocheck =  "<b>Total des p"
        Else
            strtocheck = "<b>Total parts"
        End If
 
        Dim  FichierNomenclature As String  = My. Computer . FileSystem . SpecialDirectories . Temp & "\BOM_.txt"
        If IO. File . Exists (FichierNomenclature)  Then
            IO . File . Delete (FichierNomenclature)
        End If
        Dim fs  As FileStream = Nothing
        fs =  New FileStream( FichierNomenclature, FileMode. CreateNew )
        Using sw  As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter( fs, Encoding. GetEncoding ( "iso-8859-1" ) )
            If  IO. File . Exists (txt) Then
                 Using sr As  StreamReader = New  StreamReader(txt, Encoding. GetEncoding ( "iso-8859-1" ) )
                     Dim BoolStart As Boolean = False
                     While Not sr. EndOfStream
                         Dim line As String = sr. ReadLine
                         If Left (line, 8 ) = "<a name=" Then
                             If MaLangue = "Français" Then
                                line  = "[" & Right (line, line. Length - 24 )
                                line  = Left (line, line. Length - 8 )
                                line  = line & "]"
                                sw . WriteLine (line)
                             Else
                                line  = "[" & Right (line, line. Length - 27 )
                                line  = Left (line, line. Length - 8 )
                                line  = line & "]"
                                sw . WriteLine (line)
                             End If
                         ElseIf line Like  "  <tr><td><A HREF=*</td> </tr>*"  Then
                            line  = Replace (line,  "</td><td>Assembly</td> </tr>", "" ) 'pas fait
                            line  = Replace (line,  "</td><td>Assemblage</td> </tr> ",  "" )
                            line  = Replace (line,  "  <tr><td><A HREF=", "" )
                            line  = Replace (line,  "</A></td><td>", ControlChars. Tab )
                            line  = Replace (line,  "#Bill of Material: ",  "" )
                            line  = Replace (line,  "#Nomenclature : ", "" )
                             If line. Contains ( ">" ) Then
                                 Dim lines( ) = Strings. Split (line, ">" )
                                line  = lines( 1 )
                             End If
                             Dim lines_( ) = Strings. Split (line, ControlChars. Tab )
                            line  = lines_( 0 ) & ControlChars . Tab & lines_( 1 )
                             If Strings. Left (line, 2 ) = "  " Then  line = Strings. Right (line, line. Length - 2 )
                            sw . WriteLine (line)
                         ElseIf Left (line, 14 ) = strtocheck  Then
                            sw . WriteLine ( "[ALL-BOM-APPKD]" )
                         ElseIf line Like "*<tr><td>*</td> </tr>*"  Then
                            line  = Replace (line,  "<tr><td>", "" )
                            line  = Replace (line,  "</td> </tr> ",  "" )
                            line  = Replace (line,  "</td><td>", ControlChars. Tab )
                             Dim lines_( ) = Strings. Split (line, ControlChars. Tab )
                            line  = lines_( 0 ) & ControlChars . Tab & lines_( 1 )
                             If Strings. Left (line, 2 ) = "  " Then  line = Strings. Right (line, line. Length - 2 )
                            sw . WriteLine (line)
                         Else
                             'nothing
                         End If
 
                     End While
                    sr . Close ( )
                 End Using
             End If
            sw . Close ( )
        End Using
 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi DESVOIS Kévin.  Thank for reply!
I will refer to your method.
Currently, I am using the data directly instead of reading through an intermediate file. I've done it through Tree.